# Oauth 2 pop-up window appears blank after logging in

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a React application which integrates with Quickbooks. The OAuth2.0 flow works most of the time, but for certain accounts the flow will, after logging in with username/password, present a totally blank window. It should present at that point the approval step to grant access to the service (my application).

Does anyone know what the cause may be here? If the error is on Intuit's side, is there any form of remediation?

Again, this is working with other people's production quickbooks accounts... it is only seemingly random ones that will get stuck on the blank page so that they can not authorize the app for Quickbooks.

An example of the URL we send users to is:

https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/connect/oauth2/authorize?client_id=OCLba5bC6aabduQapuVKZKzv0j3bAuYHLbkLM8yB0E7um4ieQV&redirect_uri=https://app.example.com/oauth-redirect&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting%20openid%20profile%20email%20phone%20address&state=quickbooks-9bptP0PAA1jcZ3LcpzkRZp1tKOyi0pm8HrZeXxqc

Comment: A blank page certainly sounds like a bug. Contact support?

Comment: There is no support for developers.

Comment: That's a shame!

Comment: Intuit _does_ offer support for developers. Intuit offers both support tickets ( https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/contactsupport?t=1616929774061 ) and also forums that are patrolled by the Intuit developer team ( https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/ ) @Andrew